# Sporadic Task will be run at a specific time

Tags: real-time, ada

I have a sporadic task that print something. I want to run this task at specified time i.e. 4:40PM.

I have an idea to create cyclic task, that checks time and when the time is equal to my specified time, this cyclic task realeases the barrier of sporadic task. But how to check if my specified time (represented as Unix timestamp or String) is equal to time at now? How to convert my specified time to Ada.Real_Time.Time according to Ravenscar Profile?

How can I achieve that in Ada?

Here is my code:

**sprinkler.ads**

```
pragma Profile(Ravenscar);
with GNATCOLL.Ravenscar.Simple_Cyclic_Task;
with GNATCOLL.Ravenscar.Simple_Sporadic_Task;

package Sprinkler is

    Counter : Integer := 0;
    MyTime : String := "4:45";

    procedure My_Cyclic_Operation;
    package My_Cyclic_Task is new GNATCOLL.Ravenscar.Simple_Cyclic_Task
     (Task_Priority => 10,
      Phase => 0,
      Period => 1000,
      Cyclic_Operation => My_Cyclic_Operation);


    procedure My_Sporadic_Operation;
    package My_Sporadic_Task is new GNATCOLL.Ravenscar.Simple_Sporadic_Task
        (Task_Priority => 10,
        Minimum_Interelease_Time => 1_000,
        Protocol_Ceiling => 15,
        Sporadic_Operation => My_Sporadic_Operation);

end Sprinkler;
```

**sprinkler.adb**

```
pragma Profile(Ravenscar);
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Real_Time; use Ada.Real_Time;

package body Sprinkler is

    procedure My_Cyclic_Operation is
    begin 
        -- Here I want to run My_Sporadic_Operation when time at now is equal to my specified time
        null;
    end My_Cyclic_Operation;

    procedure My_Sporadic_Operation is
    begin
        Put_Line("Sporadic at specified time!");
    end;

end Sprinkler;
```

Comment: It looks like you want to convert a civil time to a monotonic `Time`, which may have a different _epoch_. Unless your environment can synchronize with civil time, why not just `delay until` a suitable point in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The `GNATCOLL.Ravenscar` packages obey the restrictions of the Ravenscar profile, but they can be compiled into a partition that has an unrestricted profile. So, unless you’re compiling for a system that only supports Ravenscar, you can (with a small error because the calls take finite time)

- convert your 4:40 pm to `Ada.Calendar.Time`
- subtract `Ada.Calendar.Clock` to obtain a `Duration`
- use `Ada.Real_Time.To_Time_Span` to convert to `Time_Span`